# How can I increase the size of a linux partition from an unloccated

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, unallocated

I have windows 8 and Ubuntu on my laptop. I created a partition too small for linux at the begining. I wanted to increase it with 20Go from my Windows partition. I remove it from windows and it is now "unlocated".

How could I join my Linux partition with this new free space ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be possible to add  20 GB of unallocated space with the existing `/dev/sda6` ext4 partition.

- Boot from Ubuntu live disk or gparted live disk.
- Open gparted partition editor and make sure that all the partitions are unmounted.
- Right-click on the `/dev/sda3` partition and select Resize/Move option. Now add the unallocated space with it by extending the left arrow to the extreme left. So the unallocated space which was just above to the extended partition will get inside to the extended partition.
- Now the unallocated space will be on the top(just above to `/dev/sda6`) or at the bottom(just below to `/dev/sda5`) of extended partition.
- If it is located at the top of extended partition, you can directly increase the size of `/dev/sda6` root partition by right-clicking on `/dev/sda6` and selecting the Resize/Move option.
- If it is located at the bottom, you have to move the unallocated space  just below to `/dev/sda6` partition, so that you can be able to resize `/dev/sda6` with the unallocated space.
- Right-click on the `/dev/sda5` and select `Resize/Move` option. Move the dragger to the extreme right, so that the unallcated space which was present just below to the swap partition will move to the place(just above to swap partition).
- Now you can increase the size of `/dev/sda6` partition.